# CountIfs for unique values of separate criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to use COUNTIF to match criteria, where a separate criteria is unique.
For example, with the following data:

> A                B                    C                  D       E
>   RandomID Date               CustomerID typea typeb
>   44255           6/1/2015 7:34 121                      ship  con
>   44256           6/1/2015 7:46 150                      ship  tc
>   44257           6/2/2015 7:51 140                      phone con
>   44258          6/2/2015 7:52 121                      ship  tc
>   44259           6/3/2015 7:54 121                      ship  tc
>   44260          6/4/2015 7:57 150                      mail  con
>   44261         6/5/2015 8:00   199                      ship  tc

I want to count how many unique CustomerIDs there are for the following criteria: specified date range, specified typea, specified typeb.
The current formula I have can match the criteria, but counts irregardless of a value being unique. The formula I have so far is as follows (with the specified ranges of the data I'm using):

```
 >=COUNTIFS(B2:B8,">="&[@Date],B2:B8,"<="&[Date]+1,D2:D8,"ship",E2:E8,"tc").
```

I'm not sure how to check for the number of unique values of "C" that match that criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple with a PivotTable, provided that has the Distinct Count option and there are not too many dates selectively to filter:

[image: SO31080972 example]